# Repeat randomly array elements

Tags: php

```
$sql = "SELECT * from banner ORDER BY RAND() limit 6";
$x=1;

while($result =mysql_fetch_assoc($banner_arr))
{
    //print_r($result);
    $response["banner_image_".$x] = //something
    $x++;
}
```

if the database return less than 6 data, i want to repeat the data in the response array. Suppose it returns 5 data, then i want to return the response array with the 5 data and one again selected randomly from that 5 data, that is returned from the database. Basically the respose will be with 6 data all total. How i will do that?

Comment: You could repeat the query until you have enough data or union banner with itself a couple of times. Personally i'd fetch the data once, duplicate until there is enough and then randomize it using the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: can you explain how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$DESIRED_SIZE = 6;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $DESIRED_SIZE";

// TODO read from db, store into $rows array

$rows = [["1", "banner1"], ["2", "banner2"], ["3", "banner3"], ["4", "banner4"]];
$banners = [];
while (count($banners) < $DESIRED_SIZE) {
    $banners = array_merge($banners, $rows);
}
shuffle($banners);
$result = array_slice($banners, 0, $DESIRED_SIZE);
```